# Method of expanding list of dictionaries into list of formatted strings

Tags: python

I've run across a need to call out to an external executable using the subprocess module. Everything is working fine, however I'd like to improve how I'm generating the commandline arguments.

The executable's command line options require formatting as follows:
    --argname=argvalue

I currently have a list of dictionaries as follows:
    [{arg1:value1},{arg2:value2}]

What is the best method of expanding these dictionaries into their proper string format?  I'm currently iterating over the list, appending to a different list, however it feels there's a more pythonic method I should utilize.

Comment: Please include your own code, that gives us far more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
def format_dict(d):
    key = d.keys()[0]
    return '--%s=%s' % (key, d[key])

ex = [{'a':'3'}, {'b':'4'}]
print ' '.join(map(format_dict, ex)) # --a=3 --b=4
```

Comment: I've accepted your answer as it seems to best fit the spirit of the question. The map command is what I had in mind, but could not recall.

Answer (score 1):

Use `items()` as in http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-code-patterns/readability/not_using_items_to_iterate_over_a_dictionary.html

```
for key,val in d.items():
    print("{} = {}".format(key, val))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
' '.join('--{key}={value}'.format(key = k, value = v) for d in arg_list for k, v in d.items())
```

Essentially, this iterates over each dictionary in the list (`for d in arg_list`) and then iterates over the items in each dictionary (`for k, v in d.items()`). Each item is formatted into the proper form, and then all of those key-value pairs are combined.

It is equivalent to:

```
arg_list = [{arg1:value1},{arg2:value2}]
formatted_args = []

for d in arg_list:
    for k, v in d.items():
        # Format each item per dictionary
        formatted_args.append('--{key}={value}'.format(key = k, value = v))

# Combine the arguments into one string
args_string = ' '.join(formatted_args)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The map() command in another answer was what I was looking for, however I feel you're confirming that there's no silver bullet and nothing inherently wrong with my current approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 ','.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for d in arg_list for k, v in d.items())
```